# Parse same XML tag to different java objects

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I am trying to parse below xml into java objects

```
<MyCar>
    <Object name="Car's Front" type="CarFront">
        <Object name="Car's Bumper" type="Bumper"></Object>
        <Object name="Car's Headlight" type="Headlight"></Object>
        <Object name="Car's Windshield" type="Windshield"></Object>
    </Object>
</MyCar>
```

Java Code

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;

public class MyCarParser {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        xmlMapper.readValue(new File("car.xml"), MyCar.class);
    }
}

class MyCar {
    public String version;

    @JsonProperty("Object")
    public CarFront carFront; // This works
}

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
abstract class CarObjects {
    public String name;
}

class CarFront extends CarObjects {

    // ???
    public Bumper bumper;
    public Headlight headlight;
    public Windshield windshield;
}

class Bumper extends CarObjects {}
class Headlight extends CarObjects {}
class Windshield extends CarObjects {}
```

Any suggestions on what annotations/extensions I should use so that I can serialise/deserialize this XML correctly to my desired Java objects structure.

Comment: When debugging the *parsing* of XML/JSON, it's always easier to find the issues when you flip it to *generate* the XML/JSON instead, so you can see how the POJO properties map to the XML/JSON. --- E.g. you will see that `name` is generated as ab XML *element*, not as an *attribute*. That's just one of the issues.

Answer (score 0):

you have you add `@JsonSubTypes` to `CarOjects`

```
@JsonSubTypes({
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=Bumper.class, name = "Bumper"),
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=Headlight.class, name = "Headlight"),
// and so on ..
})
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
abstract class CarObjects {
    public String name;
}
```